# Do angle brackets inside a c string allow for other functionalities to take place?

Tags: c, linux, string, hash

The following statement is in a c header:

`#define FOO_TOKEN_FILE "<foofile>"`

Does this mean that the string will be replaced by the contents of a file "foofile" (or some other function), or is this just a string literal that only exists exactly as it's written?

Comment: From C's perspective, it's just a string literal that will be replaced exactly as written.  But perhaps the code is filtered through some templating system that expands it before it is seen by a C compiler.

Comment: Do you know how I might be able to check for that?

Comment: How do you use the code?  If there's a build system, you'll need to examine it and see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After preprocessing, all occurrences of `FOO_TOKEN_FILE` in the source text will be replaced with the string literal `"<foofile>"` - no further expansion or replacement will be done by the preprocessor or compiler.

If it's meant to be a placeholder for further processing, then that processing will be done by the source code that uses the macro.